# @Transactional timeout is not working in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions, namedparameterjdbctemplate

I am using Spring Boot and `JdbcTemplate` in my application. I am trying to implement timeout for select query but its not working.

My query takes more time than timeout time but still its not giving timeout exception.

```java
@Service
@Slf4j
public class SchedulerService
{

    @Autowired
    UserService userExportService;

    
    @Autowired
    private userExportDao userExportDao;
    
    @Value("${queryTest}")
    private String  queryFetchByExportFlagCustom;
    
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=10000)
    public void triggerUserExport() {

      List<UserExportCustom> userList;
      try {
        userList = userExportDao.findByExportFlag(0, queryFetchByExportFlagCustom);
        userExportService.exportUsers(userList, schedulerCount);
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

```java
@Repository
@Slf4j
public class UserExportDao extends JdbcDaoImpl<UserExportCustom, Long>
{

    
    @Autowired
    BeanPropertyRowMapper<UserExportCustom> userExportCustomRowMapper;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true, timeout = 1)
    public List<UserExportCustom> findByExportFlag(Integer exportFlag, String query)
    {
        List<UserExportCustom> userExportCustomList = null;
        try
        {
            SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("exportFlag", exportFlag, Types.INTEGER);
            userExportCustomList = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(query, namedParameters,userExportCustomRowMapper);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error("Error in findByExportFlag: \n" + e);
        }
        return userExportCustomList;
    }
}
```

```java
public class JdbcDaoImpl<T, ID> implements JdbcDao<T, ID> {

    @Autowired
    protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    protected NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public List<T> findAll() {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }

    @Override
    public T save(T api) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }

    @Override
    public T update(T api) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }

    @Override
    public T saveOrUpdate(T api) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }

    @Override
    public T findOne(String unique) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }

    @Override
    public T findOneById(ID id) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(ID id) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }

}
```

If query take more than 1 second than it should give timeout exception but it does not.

Comment: How are you calling this method? If you are calling this from another `@Transactional` this won't work. So add more information and please show how you are testing this.

Comment: @Scheduled(fixedDelay=10000)
 public void triggerUserExport() {

  List<UserExportCustom> userList;
  try {
   userList = userExportDao.findByExportFlag(0, queryFetchByExportFlagCustom);
            broadridgeValuationExportService.exportBroadridgeValuations(userList, schedulerCount);
   
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

Comment: Please add additional information as an edit not as comments, the latter is totally unreadable.

Comment: edited post details

Comment: This makes it more confusing, please add some class declarations and use code blocks per class. It is now totally unclear what is defined in which class.

Comment: @M.Deinum edited post details.

Answer (score 0):

try{}catch{} will lead  @Transactional to fail ,remove try catch

Comment: tried just now but still not working